# CodeIgniter4 namespace repeating itself: Controller or its method is not found: \\App\\Controllers\\App\\Controllers\\TypeBloodController::index

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am unable to create a Restful API using the CodeIgniter 4 framework.
I am using `$routes->resource()` to define the methods. However, I am unable to get `http://localhost:8080/type-blood` and other addresses to return what I want.

I correctly configured the database in the project and made a selection to see the data.

###### What return to me in Postman is this:

```
{
  "title": "CodeIgniter\\Exceptions\\PageNotFoundException",
  "type": "CodeIgniter\\Exceptions\\PageNotFoundException",
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Controller or its method is not found: \\App\\Controllers\\App\\Controllers\\TypeBloodController::index",
  "file": "/home/faker/CodeIgniter/c4/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/CodeIgniter.php",
  "line": 988,
  "trace": [
    {
      "file": "/home/faker/CodeIgniter/c4/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/CodeIgniter.php",
      "line": 988,
      "function": "forPageNotFound",
      "class": "CodeIgniter\\Exceptions\\PageNotFoundException",
      "type": "::"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/faker/CodeIgniter/c4/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/CodeIgniter.php",
      "line": 370,
      "function": "display404errors",
      "class": "CodeIgniter\\CodeIgniter",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/faker/CodeIgniter/c4/public/index.php",
      "line": 79,
      "function": "run",
      "class": "CodeIgniter\\CodeIgniter",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "/home/faker/CodeIgniter/c4/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Commands/Server/rewrite.php",
      "line": 47,
      "args": [
        "/home/faker/CodeIgniter/c4/public/index.php"
      ],
      "function": "require_once"
    }
  ]
}
```

`Route.php`

```
<?php

use CodeIgniter\Router\RouteCollection;
use App\Controllers\TypeBloodController;

/**
 * @var RouteCollection $routes
 */

$routes->resource('type-blood', ['controller' => TypeBloodController::class]);

$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');
```

`TypeBloodController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use App\Models\TypeBloodModel;

class TypeBloodController extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $type_blood = new TypeBloodModel();
        $datas = $type_blood->findAll();
        $this->response->setContentType('application/json');
        return $this->response->setJSON($datas);
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $type_blood = new TypeBloodModel();
        $validation = $type_blood->getRuleGroup('blood_store');
        $this->response->setContentType('application/json');
        return $this->response->setStatusCode(200)->setJSON(['message' => 'Insertion done.']);
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $type_blood = new TypeBloodModel();
        $register = $type_blood->find($id);
        if (!$type_blood) {
            return $this->response->setStatusCode(404)->setJSON(['message' => "Register not found."]);
        }
        $this->response->setContentType('application/json');
        return $this->response->setJSON($register);
    }

    public function update($id)
    {
        $type_blood = new TypeBloodModel();
        $register = $type_blood->find($id);
        if (!$register) {
            return $this->response->setStatusCode(404)->setJSON(['message' => "Register updated."]);
        }
        $validation = $registro->getRuleGroup('blood_update');
        $this->response->setContentType('application/json');
        return $this->response->setJSON($register);
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $type_blood = new TypeBloodModel();
        $register = $type_blood->find($id);
        if (!$register) {
            return $this->response->setStatusCode(404)->setJSON(['message' => "Register not found"]);
        }
        $register->delete($id);
        $this->response->setContentType('application/json');
        return $this->response->setStatusCode(200)->setJSON(['message' => 'Exclusion done.']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Explanation

If the controller is provided without a leading backslash (\), the default namespace will be prepended.

[Default Namespace](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/routing.html#default-namespace)

> When matching a controller to a route, the router will add the default
> namespace value to the front of the controller specified by the route.
> By default, this value is `App\Controllers`.

###### Excerpt from [`CodeIgniter4/app/Config/Routing.php`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/e346a6fabd7ff12605d686441360da3274a57911/app/Config/Routing.php#L38)

```php
class Routing extends BaseRouting
{
    // ...
    public string $defaultNamespace = 'App\Controllers';
    // ...
}
```

> If you set the value empty string (''), it leaves each route to
> specify the fully namespaced controller:

##### Solution

`app/Config/Routes.php`

1. Set your default namespace to an empty string (''). I.e: `$routes->setDefaultNamespace('');`
2. Convert all your string-based controller syntax to array callable syntax. I.e:

   - ***Instead of:❌*** `$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');`
   - ***Use:✅*** `$routes->get('/', [Home::class, 'index']);`
   - The [array callable syntax](https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/incoming/routing.html#array-callable-syntax) (*Since v4.2.0.*) also allows for quick navigation to your method or controller when working with an IDE or code editor.

##### Example

```php
<?php

use CodeIgniter\Router\RouteCollection;
use App\Controllers\TypeBloodController;
use App\Controllers\Home;

/**
 * @var RouteCollection $routes
 */
$routes->setDefaultNamespace('');

$routes->get('/', [Home::class, 'index']);

$routes->resource('type-blood', ['controller' => TypeBloodController::class]);
```

Comment: ```POST```, ```PATCH``` and ```DELETE``` didn't work.

Comment: @DevoloperBebop  It looks like you have been using Laravel or something similar before coming to CodeIgniter4.  CodeIgniter4 uses different method names for _'resource'_ routes. Instead of: `store() -> create()` and `destroy($id) -> delete($id)` Reference: [Resource Routes](https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/incoming/restful.html#resource-routes)

Comment: @DevoloperBebop Another tip is that, your Controller may instead [extend ResourceController](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/14b4350b3685d33018ce7ba0c7d0a368f25962ce/system/RESTful/ResourceController.php#L22).

Comment: @DevoloperBebop When your Controller extends the ResourceController, you wouldn't need to manually set the _'Content-Type'_ in every _'resource'_ method.  You would simply use: return `$this->respondUpdated(...)`, `$this->respondDeleted(...)`, `$this->respondCreated()`, and `$this->respond(...)` where applicable. Resource: [system/API/ResponseTrait.php](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/14b4350b3685d33018ce7ba0c7d0a368f25962ce/system/API/ResponseTrait.php#L149)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot use a qualified names for specifying the *controller* option.
According the documentation it is possible, but it seems to be a minor bug, because in this case it duplicates the namespaces.

You can always check your routes with the spark command. Check the handler column.

```
php spark routes
```

In my case the handler is: **\App\Controllers\App\Controllers\Home::index**, but it should be: **\App\Controllers\Home::index**

You can fix it simply:

```php
$routes->resource('type-blood', ['controller' => 'TypeBloodController']);
```

Note: if your resource and controller names are the same, you can omit the *controller* option. So you can technically change the name of the controller to *TypeBlood* and file name to *TypeBlood.php*. Then simply delete the *controller* option.

Note: if your controller is not in the App\Controllers namespace, you can specify with the *namespace* option. For example:

```php
$routes->resource('type-blood', ['controller' => 'TypeBloodController', 'namespace' => 'NotApp\Controllers']);
```

I created a [bug issue report](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/issues/8248), so maybe it will be fixed in the later version.

**UPDATE**:
The documentation will be improved in the later version. You can use the following (Fully qualified name) without changing the *default namespace* configuration:

```php
$routes->resource('test1', ['namespace' => '\\', 'controller' => Home::class]);
$routes->resource('test2', ['controller' => '\\' . Home::class]);
$routes->resource('test3', ['controller' => 'Home']);
```

Source: https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/issues/8248